# C++ call constructor from class pointer?

Tags: c++, types, generic-programming

I would like to be able to initialize a class from a string (I give "MyClass" and it would create an object MyClass).

I know it is not possible to do that so I created a class that has a map with a string as a key and a pointer to a function (that creates the object) as a value.

Creating dynamically the object is not a problem with this and my map.

```
template<typename T> JsonSerializable* createInstance() { return new T; }
```

My problem is that I want to add dynamically the classes to my map. Is that possible ?
How can I do :

```
void MyFactory::addNewClass(std::string& name, class c)
{
    map[name]=&createInstance<c>();
}
```

Can I pass a pointer or something to the class itself (not the object) ? And use that to create dynamically everything.

If it is not possible I will have to hardcode it.

Comment: You probably want `map[name]=&createInstance<c>;`. You want to put the function in there, not the object. I think. If you show the type of `map` it would become more clear.

Comment: You may be interested in [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Comment: @nwp I already corrected that, was a bad copy past from me.
My problem is not to call the constructor, my problem is to pass the class as a class and not an object.

Comment: You pass it like `template <class T> void MyFactory::addNewClass(std::string& name){map[name]=&createInstance<T>;}` to be called like `myFactory.addNewClass<Foo>("Foo");`.

Comment: I think he cannot create a `map` of different value types, as each `createInstance<c>` is different type

Comment: @mco Looks to me like each `createInstance<c>` has type `JsonSerializable *(*)();`.

Comment: Before you really make a `SuperBase`, [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d7a8dcbb181436a) is what I meant put all together. It is using raw `new` and `delete` so it will be full of memory leaks which you could fix by using `std::unique_ptr<JsonSerializable>` instead of `JsonSerializable *` and you probably want those classes to not be empty, but it is a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.. So if you're using C++11 then lambdas can be of some help in getting the generic behaviour you're looking for.

First of all, we need a `SuperBase` from which all the classes shall be derived like this

```
class SuperBase {};
class A : public SuperBase {};

class B: public SuperBase {};
```

Then create a map which takes `std::string` as key and `std::function` as value.

```
map<string,std::function<SuperBase*()>> myMap;
```

The function return type is `SuperBase` and the `addNewClass` function can be defined as

```
template <typename type>
void addNewClass(std::string name) {
    myMap[name] = []() { return new type();};
  }
```

So from the main function you can call the function as

```
addNewClass<A>("A");
addNewClass<B>("B");
```

Then while iterating you can call the function to get you the desired pointer

```
 for( auto mapPair : myMap) {
        cout<<mapPair.first<<endl;
        SuperBase * sBase = mapPair.second();
    }
```

Remember, you need `virtual` functions in `SuperBase` to have polymorphic behaviour and then everything should work

Hope it helps

Comment: You need to specify the return type of the lambda, otherwise it will be inferred to be `type`. Do this: ```[]() -> SuperBase* { return new type();};```

Comment: Correct. Its a good practice but not mandatory as it manages to deduce itself for all types..